# The right way to calculate the derivative of sigmoid function in Python

Tags: python, math, sympy, derivative, sigmoid

I was walking through [this article](https://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/27/python-network-part2/). In the code, the author mentions that the following function finds the derivative:

```
# convert output of sigmoid function to its derivative
def sigmoid_output_to_derivative(output):
    return output*(1-output)
```

I couldn't really understand how the derivative was found here. Would using [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) to find the derivative be a better option? How can I do it in the example shown in the article, especially that `output` will be a list similar to the following:

```
[[ 0.44856632  0.51939863  0.45968497  0.59156505]
 [ 0.28639589  0.32350963  0.31236398  0.51538526]
 [ 0.40795614  0.62674606  0.23841622  0.49377636]
 [ 0.25371248  0.42628115  0.14321233  0.41732254]]
```

So, the bottom line is:

- How was the derivative calculated in the original article? I understand the formula in the code, but, is there some theoretical basis?
- Can we use another way to find the derivative? A more clear way maybe?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sigmoid function is useful mainly because its derivative is easily computable in terms of its output; the derivative is `f(x)*(1-f(x))`.

Therefore, finding the derivative using a library based on the sigmoid function is not necessary as the mathematical derivative (above) is already known. For the derivation, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78575/derivative-of-sigmoid-function-sigma-x-frac11e-x).